# General form of isometric projection from $\mathbb{R}^M$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assuming $M \ge N$, I guess the projection is generally represented by the $N \times M$ matrix, and isometry would require that its "determinant" = 1?  However, the determinant is not defined for non-square matrices...

Comment: What is the determinant of a non-square matrix?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering also, and it doesn't exist...

Comment: Also, shouldn't the matrix be $N \times M$?

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: What is a isometric projection? In general, projection does not preserve lengths.

Comment: I mean it should preserve Euclidean distances.